# Does median filter increase the redundancy in the filtered image

Tags: image-processing, filter, median

I have filtered an image which is affected with impulse noise or Gaussian noise or mixed noise(both impulse noise or Gaussian noise) using median filter. I think filtering an image using median filter will increase the redundancy of the image. Am I correct? Could someone explain me whether the redundancy information will increase or decrease after the applying median filter to the image.

As we are using median values to replace the corrupted pixels, the filtered pixel values will be in a same range(may not be very close). Therefore, I think this will increase the redundancy of an image. I am a student and I am unsure about it. Please explain me  whether the redundancy information will increase or decrease after the applying median filter to the image. I want to check this using matlab but I don't know how to find the redundancy of an image in matlab.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us why you think it will? What resources have you looked at, or do you have available?

Comment: @ Hugh Nolan As we are using median values to replace the corrupted pixels, the filtered pixel values will be in a same range(may not be very close). Therefore, I think this will increase the redundancy of an image. I am a student, I am unsure about it. Please explain me  whether the redundancy information will increase or decrease after the applying median filter to the image. I want to check this using matlab but I don't know how to find the redundancy of an image in matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot introduce any new information with a filter (as it is based on the image content alone), you can only decrease the information content, or at best leave it the same. From an information theory point of view, this would increase redundancy if you are filling the same size array with less information content. But there are many definitions of image redundancy, so it depends which you are using (I came across spatial, coding, interpixel redundancy in a quick search). This will then determine how you should compute it in matlab - `entropy` will probably be a useful functions, if you are looking from information theory perspective.

http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~geelong/spatial/ - gives some info on spatial redundancy.
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/photo-and-graphic-manipulation/9789332501454/chapter-5-image-compression/ch5_sub5_2_xhtml - the preview gives a simple equation for coding redundancy.